# Deploying ASP.NET 5 RC1 WebApi with Azure Storage Library 6.2.0 or 6.2.2 preview causing 500 error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-deployment, serilog

If attempt to create a basic ASP.NET 5 WebApi with the following code and deploy to Azure I get a 500 error on startup. I've tried with WindowsAzure.Storage 6.2.0 and with 6.2.2 preview. Both give me the same results. If I use 4.2.0 it works fine, but I'd like to use the latest version of the Azure storage library if possible. Any suggestions?

To reproduce this issue make the following changes to basic ASP.NET 5 WebAPI project and deploy to Azure.

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Set up configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        builder.AddUserSecrets();
    }

    Configuration = builder.Build();

    var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(Configuration["Azure:Storage:AccountName"], Configuration["Azure:Storage:AccountKey"]);
    var storage = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);
    var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.AzureTableStorage(storage)
        .CreateLogger();

    loggerFactory.AddSerilog(loggerConfig);

    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("WebApi.Startup");

    _logger.LogInformation("Starting Web API");

}
```

project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Serilog.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final-10083",
    "Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage": "1.5.11",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "6.2.2-preview",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final-10092"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```